# Is there an attribute other than AllowHTML to allow XML content in a view?

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc-5

I am coding a C# MVC 5 internet application where a view has an input for an XSD string and an input for an XML string. Is there an attribute other than `[AllowHtml]` that should be added to the viewmodel to allow XML input?

I do not want malicious HTML code to be returned when the view is posted, and as such, I would rather use a different method than the `[AllowHtml]` attribute.

Comment: What is your actual problem?  Does `AllowHtml` not work?

Comment: AllowHtml does work, I just do not want to allow malicious code to be sent from the view.

Comment: Ok so it sounds like your real problem is... *Using `AllowHtml` how do I scrub the value to prevent malicious code*..

Comment: Yes, but specific for XML. I have used AntiXSS for sanitizing data, but the data sanitizes HTML, not specific to XML.

Comment: If XML is storing data, what is the security issue?

Comment: Can HTML with JavaScript code be entered into an view input that is associated with an AllowHtml attribute such that the JavaScript can be executed?